# Scan a NAS Device with Microsoft Forefront Endpoint Protection

Tags: network-attached-storage, malware, microsoft-forefront-2010

We are having problems with viruses sneaking through our virus scanner and onto our NAS and I want to scan the whole NAS.  If I attempt to run a scan on the whole drive using the GUI for Forefront Endpoint Protection it sits at the initial screen without progressing.  I can however scan a single smaller folder without a problem.  I could sit here and scan each folder individually but with 100+ folders it's going to take a while.

My hope was that I could initiate a scan on the whole drive or each folder through the command line but the command line option will only accept a file.

Is there a way to fix this?  I'm assuming I could start the GUI on a Friday and let it run but if it doesn't finish there wouldn't be a way to resume the scan.

Comment: If you think it's a sizing issue, try deep-mapping a drive letter, see if it's any better. i.e. net use * \\server\share\path\that\gets\even\longer